# Display vega visualization using react-vega and next.js

Tags: reactjs, vega

I am trying to display a visualization created with vega. The template I am using for the website is [react-portfolio-template](https://github.com/chetanverma16/react-portfolio-template) that uses `next.js`. The spec and data are from the [react-vega examples](https://github.com/vega/react-vega/tree/master/packages/react-vega-demo/stories/vega). Here are the component and the page that will display the visualization.

```js
// component file
import { createClassFromSpec, Vega } from 'react-vega';
import spec1 from "../../data/spec1.ts";
import data from "../../data/data_test.json"

const BarChart = createClassFromSpec({ spec: spec1 });
const PropertiesViz= () => {

  return (<>
    <Vega data={data} spec={spec1} />
    <BarChart data={data} />
    </>
  );
};

export default PropertiesViz
```

```js
// page file
import PropertiesViz from "../../components/VegaVisualization"
import React from "react";


export default function XAIEvalFramework() {
  return ( <PropertiesViz />
  )
}
```

Everytime I hit the page I get the following error:

```
Server Error
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Call Stack
<unknown>
file:///[path]react-portfolio-template-main/node_modules/vega-embed/build/vega-embed.js (4334)
wrapSafe
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js (915:16)
Module._compile
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js (963:27)
Object.Module._extensions..js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js (1027:10)
Module.load
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js (863:32)
Function.Module._load
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js (708:14)
Module.require
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js (887:19)
require
internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js (74:18)
Object.<anonymous>
file:///[path]react-portfolio-template-main/node_modules/react-vega/lib/utils/updateSingleDatasetInView.js (6:18)
Module._compile
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js (999:30)
Object.Module._extensions..js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js (1027:10)
```

I have tried both suggested ways to display the visualization: using `createClassFromSpec` and also  the `Vega` component but nothing works. I still get the same error.

I don't think there's anything wrong with the specs and the data because I am using the same files as the react-vega exmaples. Could there be an interaction happening with next.js? Has anyone encountered this problem before?

Answer (score 0):

Try making the component client component by adding "use client" at top